# Remotely accessing OSX machine behind firewall

Tags: macos, ssh, firewall, remote-access

I need some way to remotely access an OSX machine that sits behind a remote firewall  (if it weren't for the firewall thing I could just ssh into it, but I have no control over the remote firewall to open ports).  My local machine runs Linux, and I do have complete control over it and the local router's firewall.  What are my options?

Comment: TeamViewer doesn't require you to punch a hole in the far-end firewall

Comment: What ports are open in the firewall?  Just have sshd listen on an open port in addition to port 22.  For example, if https is open, add a `Port 443` line to your sshd_config file in addition to the `Port 22` line.  Then just add a `-p 443` parameter to your ssh command when you connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SSH, it's possible to forward the SSH port of your remote machine to your local machine, by first establishing a tunnel from your remote machine to your local machine. This approach would basically be SSH over SSH, which will have a tonne of overheads, but *should* work...

Assuming your REMOTE machine (behind the firewall) has hostname remotebox, and your local machine has hostname localbox, running the following (from the remote machine) should forward port 22 from the remote machine to port 23 on your local box:

```
ssh -R 23:localhost:22 user@localbox
```

You'd then be able to connect to remotebox from localbox by running:

```
ssh user@localhost -p23
```

on your local machine.